# Time Format hh:nn:ss in access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

We have reports run for us that shows the amount of time a user has been logged in. The report is in excel and shows the cell format as text, the time shown in the cell is in this format 08:10:31

When I import this to access it shows as a 5 digit number (e.g 20326)

How do I get access to show it in the same format that its in excel?

I have tried changing the table format in access to hh:nn:ss but then the cell shows as blank.

Help

Comment: This one may explain why you got digit (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450055/when-i-import-the-date-format-in-exceldd-mm-yyyy-to-msaccess-it-is-showing-non), and `hh:nn:ss` is typo? should it be `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: @Alex mm is month.

Comment: I suggest you import to an existing empty table with a date format for that column.

Comment: @Fionnuala, you are correct, confuse with other date time format

Comment: Thanks for the input all - Fionnuala I will also try that method now

Comment: BTW testing with Office 2016, an straight import of time works for me.

Comment: I tried your method but doesn't work unfortunately. When I import the data nothing at all shows in the table when changing the format to hh:nn:ss